# Azure Mobile Services - IMobileServiceSyncTable PullAsync does not fill local sync table

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure Mobile Services for my Xamarin.iOS app. I have my App Service set up both in the backend and on the client side and I'm able to successfully register an account on my app and see the entry in the respective table in the backend.

When I try to populate the local sync table however, using the call to `PullAsync`, the sync table is always empty, even when I try to return all the records in that table, without using any filters in my query.

I'm not sure why the `PullAsync` doesn't populate my sync tables, even when there are no exceptions.

Below is my code:

**Initializing the Local Store**

```
public class AzureMobileClientServiceDataManager : IAzureMobileClientServiceDataManager, IMobileServiceSyncHandler
{

    const string localDbPath = "sample.db";
    MobileServiceSQLiteStore store;

    MobileServiceClient client { get; set; }

    public AzureMobileClientServiceDataManager(IAzureMobileClientService azureMobileClientService)
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        SQLitePCL.CurrentPlatform.Init();

        //Initialize the Mobile service client with the Mobile App URL,Gatewaty URL and Key
        client = azureMobileClientService.GetMobileServiceClientInstance();
    }

    public async Task InitializeStoreAsync()
    {
        store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(localDbPath);
        store.DefineTable<Account>();
        store.DefineTable<UserProfile>();
        store.DefineTable<Purchase>();

        await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, this);

    }

    public MobileServiceClient GetInstance()
    {
        return client;
    }

    public Task OnPushCompleteAsync(MobileServicePushCompletionResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error :" + error.RawResult);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<JObject> ExecuteTableOperationAsync(IMobileServiceTableOperation operation)
    {
        return operation.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}

public interface IAzureMobileClientServiceDataManager
{
    Task InitializeStoreAsync();

    MobileServiceClient GetInstance();

}
```

Right after a successful registration of a new user, I call this function to populate my tables.

```
public async Task<Result<bool>> PopulateData()
    {
       try{

       await accountTable.PullAsync("localAccount", accountTable.Where(ac => ac.Id == mobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.UserId));
       await userProfileTable.PullAsync("localUserProfile", userProfileTable.Where(up => up.AccountId == mobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.UserId));


      return Result<bool>.Success(true);

    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Result<bool>.Failure(ex, ex.StackTrace);
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an azuredatamanager per table? If so, you are going to run into problems. The MobileServiceClient is meant to be global, and you will bump into issues with multiple tables, as you are re-initializing the table each time.

Also, try adding logging SQLite store to your app, which will log all local database statements, here's a sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs